# is Storm API available for killing a component/submitting topology

Tags: api, testing, apache-storm

I'd like to know if there is an API available for Storm which can be used for various functions such as submitting a topology, shutting down a running bolt and so on. I'm involved in a project for testing a component which uses Storm as its processing engine. I'd also love to hear experiences of folks who have been involved in testing Storm related projects, the various testcases they worked on etc.

Comment: have you tried running any [sample](https://github.com/nathanmarz/storm-starter) topology?

Comment: Yes. I have setup a storm cluster, and have been running a topology successfully. My question is related to system failure testing of storm components..

Comment: could you be more specific? you are asking here about the API which is a different than the fault tolerant mechanism

Comment: I'm asking if there is any API for doing various storm related functionalities like submitting/killing topology. I'd also like to know the various testing approaches used for testing Storm.

Comment: For system failure testing, I'd like to know how I can kill a particular bolt and check if it is auto recovery functionality..

Comment: Have you tried [Command line client](https://github.com/nathanmarz/storm/wiki/Command-line-client) and Strom UI?

Comment: Yes I have been using them. But I'd like to programmatically do the same..so it would be cleaner code if I can use something that storm provides than remote sshing to the machine and running the storm jar command from there..

Answer (score 0):

Depends on exactly what you're looking for. If you look at the implementation of the `storm` executable you use for submitting topologies, etc., you're basically looking at an API for doing what you want. Depending on how much encapsulation you want, you may have to add a layer on top of what it uses.

Comment: Yeah I understand. Usually what are the approaches used for testing Storm? I'm looking for something which can be used to shut down a running bolt etc..

Comment: Ah. In that case I don't think there is a best practice, though I've generally done it by writing unit tests, which don't require running Storm, and then using the command line for integration tests since I typically just do one per topology to make sure it can complete a "normal" workload.